# SQLAlchemy Unicode Problems in Exceptions

Tags: postgresql, unicode, sqlalchemy, python-2.x

I'm working on a Flask app with a postgres/SQLAlchemy/Flask-Admin. However, in the Admin interface, any DB error that contain Unicode letters can't be reported since `unicode(exc)` raises `UnicodeDecodeError`.

I was able to locate that problem to [`sqlalchemy.exc`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/exc.py)

```
class StatementError(SQLAlchemyError):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

And reproduce the problem by with:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__="a"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    name2 = Column(String, nullable=False)

session = Session()
a = A(name=u"עברית")
session.add(a)

try:
    session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))
    print("------------------")
    print(unicode(e))
```

Which returns:

```
ProgrammingError('(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "name" of relation "a" does not exist\nLINE 1: INSERT INTO a (name, name2) VALUES (\'\xd7\xa2\xd7\x91\xd7\xa8\xd7\x99\xd7\xaa\', NULL) RETURNING...\n                       ^\n',)
------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(unicode(e))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 118: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And I currently solve it by replacing the relevant exceptions with my classes that decode from `utf-8`. However, this is a terrible hack, and I'm looking for a proper solution:

- Is there way to configure SQLAlchemy to automatically decode the received error messages?
- Is there way to configure Postgres to output messages in `latin` encoding (less favorable, but accetable)
- Is there way to make `unicode` try to decode by `utf-8` instead of `ascii`/`latin`?
- Is there any way to resolve it at all???

(The problem is relevant only to Python2. In Python3 the code above works. I believe it's because the default encoding is `utf-8`)

Comment: I would call that a bug in SQLAlchemy tbh, `__str__` should return a `str` and `__unicode__` should return a `unicode`. You should file this as an issue. You can work around it by doing `print(str(e).decode("utf-8"))` everywhere, which is tedious, but not the worst thing in the world.

Comment: I will file this as an issue. But I can't fix it as suggested, as the relevant code is in Flask-Admin. I need a solution that is somewhat more global.

Comment: @tmrlvi Could you please post here link to the issue you filed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think that patching SQLAlchemy from your application is the right reasonably clean solution.  Here's why:

- You've identified something that generally is agreed to be a bug in SQLAlchemy.
- You can write a patch that will behave the same for all situations that SQLAlchemy currently works with.  That is, your patch will not break existing code
- The probability is very high that even if SQLAlchemy is fixed your patch will be harmless.
- Making this change reduces the impact of the SQLAlchemy bug throughout your code over solutions like changing every place where exceptions might be printed.
- Changing PostGres to return latin1 encoding actually wouldn't help because python is using the ascii encoding, which would give the same error when given a latin1 string.  Also, changing PostGres to return latin1 errors would probably involve changing the connection encoding; that likely creates issues for unicode data.

Here's a simple program that patches sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError and tests the patch.  If you wanted you could even try generating a exception including unicode, convert that to unicode, and only apply the patch if that raises UnicodeDecodeError.  If you did that, your patch would automatically stop being applied when sqlalchemy fixes the issue.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sqlalchemy.exc import StatementError

def statement_error_unicode(self):
    return unicode(str(self), 'utf-8')
# See <link to sqlalchemy issue>; can be removed once we require a
# version of sqlalchemy with a fix to that issue
StatementError.__unicode__ = statement_error_unicode

message = u'Sqlalchemy unicode '
message_str = message.encode('utf-8')
error = StatementError(message_str, 'select * from users', tuple(), '')
print unicode(error)
```